# Run a command in an interactive shell with ssh after sourcing .bashrc

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, alias

I want to ssh into a remote Ubuntu computer, source my `.bashrc` and run a command that depends on parameters set by that `.bashrc`. All that in an interactive shell that doesn't close after the command is done.

What I tried until now is

```
ssh user@remote_computer -t 'bash -l -c "my_alias;bash"'
```

or just

```
ssh user@remote_computer -t "my_alias;bash"
```

This works for general commands (like `ls` for example) but when I try to run an alias defined in `.bashrc` I get an error:

```
bash: my_alias: command not found
```

But then when I write it manually again and run it, it works!

So how can I make sure the the `.bashrc` is sourced before the command is called?

Comment: The post is confusing. I recommend not to abuse running commands like that ; nevertheless if bash or a bash command is being invoked I would say .bashrc is supposed to run. There are evidently some differences or peculiarities of running a command like that, and for more serious applications, I would recommend Ansible or puppet.

Comment: I edited my question. The second command is more simple and does the same, but still without sourcing .bashrc before.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Abuse?? how can you call such a simple thing abuse?? automatically running a command after logging into a remote machine with ssh, it is as simple as that. Any external tool that would be deployed for such a ridiculously small task would be an overkill

Comment: Just a figure of speaking, was not intended to be used in a broader term. Use them when you need it, however using them is a not as peaceful as it seems. Nevertheless, for future references, have a look at Ansible, you would be amazed how lightweight it is actually. I often do run also commands via ssh.

Answer (score 21):

The problem is that you are trying to run an alias in a non-interactive shell. When you run `ssh user@computer command`, `command` is run non-interactively.

Non interactive shells don't read aliases (from man bash):

> Aliases  are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using
>          shopt (see the description of shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).

It works if you run it again manually because the final `bash` command starts an interactive shell so your aliases are now available.

As an alternative, you could launch an interactive shell (`bash -i`) instead of a simple login shell (`bash -l`) on the remote machine to run your alias:

```
ssh user@remote_computer -t 'bash -ic "my_alias;bash"'
```

This seems a very complicated approach though. You haven't explained why exactly you need to do this but consider these alternatives:

1. Just start a normal login interactive shell on the remote machine and run the command manually:

   ```
   user@local $ ssh user@remote
   user@remote $ my_alias
   ```
2. If you always want that alias to be run when you connect to this computer, edit the `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile`, if present) of the remote computer and add this line at the end:

   ```
   my_alias
   ```

   Because `~/.profile` is read each time a login shell is started (so, each time you connect via `ssh`, for example), that will cause `my_alias` to be run each time you connect.

   Note that by default, login shells read `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` and ignore `~/.bashrc`. Some distributions (Debian and its derivatives and Arch, for example)  distributions like Ubuntu have their default `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` files source `~/.bashrc` which means that your aliases defined in `~/.bashrc` will also be available in a login shell. This isn't true for all distributions, so you might have to edit your `~/.profile` manually to have it source `~/.bashrc`. Also note that if `~/.bash_profile` exists, `~/.profile` will be ignored by bash.

Comment: So would you suggest having the aliases defined in a alias_profile and call them from .profile or .bash_profile?

Comment: @Mehdi that will depend on what you want to do. On your Ubuntu system, `~/.basyrc` is automatically read by `~./profile`, so any aliases defined in `~/.bashrc` will also be available to any shells reading `~/.profile`. All you really needed to do to get this to work was to explicitly start an interactive shell (`-i`).

Answer (score 5):

I had to comment a part of my .bashrc that prevented aliases from being used
and add a expand_aliases command.
This was commented

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
#case $- in
#    *i*) ;;
#      *) return;;
#esac
```

And this was added

```
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
  shopt -s expand_aliases
fi
```

Then my command worked:

```
ssh user@remote_computer -t "my_alias;bash"
```