# ssh to execute remote command under interactive shell

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, remote, executable

Very similar with [Run a command in an interactive shell with ssh after sourcing .bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243821/run-a-command-in-an-interactive-shell-with-ssh-after-sourcing-bashrc), yet the answer there doesn't work for me.

I want to to execute remote command via ssh under the full interactive shell. I.e.,
run a remote command under the login shell, with some parameters.

Basically, I need the following two cases to work:

```
ssh user@remote_computer -t bash -l -c '/bin/echo PATH is $PATH'
ssh user@remote_computer -t 'bash -l -c "java -version"'
```

But currently I got a blank line from case 1, and `java: command not found` from case 2:

```
$ ssh user@remote_computer -t bash -l -c '/bin/echo PATH is $PATH'

Connection to remote_computer closed.

$ ssh user@remote_computer -t bash -l -c 'true; /bin/echo PATH is $PATH'
PATH is /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
Connection to remote_computer closed.

ssh user@remote_computer -t bash -l -c 'true; java -version'
bash: line 1: java: command not found
Connection to remote_computer closed.
```

**UPDATE:**

At least two people think it is a quoting problem, but please can any one explain why it is a quoting problem, and how can I get what I wanted above. For e.g., this is also what I had tried:

```
ssh user@remote_computer -t 'bash -l -c "java -version"'
bash: line 1: java: command not found
Connection to remote_computer closed.
```

And I've run out of ideas how to quote it in a different way. Please help!

If I run the same command after `ssh user@remote_computer`, I'll get:

```
$ bash -l -c "java -version"
openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.56+19-CA (build 11.0.15+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.56+19-CA (build 11.0.15+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

So this is clearly not a quoting problem to me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what happens when you try the solutions from the question you linked to. Also, try `ssh user@remote_computer -t bash -l -c 'true; echo PATH is $PATH'` does that work as expected?

Comment: @terdon, OP updated. The output of PATH is obviously not from the login shell.

Comment: See the paragraph named "Discussion" and the procedure in the paragraph named "Solution" in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1534401/432690). Also this: [*How can I single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?*](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690)

Comment: I don't understand @KamilMaciorowski, please see my updated OP.

Comment: `ssh user@remote_computer -t bash -l -c '/bin/echo PATH is $PATH'` does what `ssh user@remote_computer -t 'bash -l -c /bin/echo PATH is $PATH'` does, so the ultimate `bash` runs `/bin/echo` without arguments, hence a single newline (not "nothing") in the output. It's obviously not what you expected, so we assumed this is the problem you want to solve. `ssh user@remote_computer -t 'bash -l -c "java -version"'` is properly quoted and if the real problem is with it then the question should be reopened. But please try to remove or fix improperly quoted commands, as they only divert attention.

Comment: Some points that you’re missing: (1)  `ssh  u@h  A B C`  does  `sh -c  'A B C'` on host `h`.  This looks obvious, but it can surprise you if  `A`, `B` and/or `C` contain spaces.  For example, `ssh  u@h  cp "file 1" "file 2"` gets you `cp file 1 file 2` (losing the word boundaries).  (2)  ``sh -c D E F G`` runs `D` with `$0`=`E`, `$1`=`F` and `$2`=`G`. … … … … … … … … Look at your error message: `-version: line 1: java: command not found`.  `ssh` is running  `sh -c  'bash -l -c java -version'`, losing the fact that you meant `java -version` to be an unbroken string  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  — and ``bash -l -c java -version`` runs (tries to run) `java` with no arguments, but with `$0`=`'-version'` (hence the error message).  While I sympathize with your frustration, please read the linked pages and try to understand them.  … … … … … … And fix your question to say that `ssh  u@h  sh -c 'echo foo'`  *outputs **a blank line**,* not “nothing”.

Comment: something like `printf 'java -version' | ssh user@remote_computer 'bash -l'` might be less bad than trying to conjure an interactive shell out of a `-c` shell and other such quoting fun

Comment: That could be the answer @thrig, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell `-c` command over SSH is problematic here; there are tricky
quoting issues and it is not clear to me who is running what when. Here
`customjava` is only known to something that reads `~/.bashrc` for
testing purposes. ZSH is my default shell.

```
$ ssh -t localhost bash -c 'source ~/.bashrc;customjava -version'
/home/jhqdoe/.bashrc: line 0: source: filename argument required
source: usage: source filename [arguments]
zsh:1: command not found: customjava
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
$ ssh -t localhost bash -c ':;source ~/.bashrc;customjava -version'
java version 99999
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

I guess you could `strace` things and `ssh -v -v -v` and probably
source code dive to figure out exactly what is different between the
above two commands (`:` is the null command and is less typing than
`true`) but if things are already this fragile and hard to debug I
would look for some other solution. My preference is usually to quote
the whole command:

```
$ ssh localhost 'bash -ic "customjava -version"'
java version 99999
```

However this will probably become too complicated if there are more
elaborate quoting needs and variable substitutions involved in the
commands. (Complicated shell quoting is not the sort of thing I want to
debug at 2AM in the morning, so I tend to avoid it by default.)

### Instead Pipe

Another method is to pipe the commands to the required shell; this
minimizes the complexity on the command to run to just a shell
invocation that is probably optional:

```
$ printf 'customjava -version'"\n" | ssh localhost 'bash -i'
bash$ customjava -version
java version 99999
bash$ exit
$ printf 'customjava -version'"\n" | ssh localhost 'bash -l'
java version 99999
```

The downside here is that standard input is not a terminal, so if a
command on the other end really needs a terminal, this will not work.
There may be warnings about this.

```
$ printf 'customjava -version'"\n" | ssh localhost
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
zsh: command not found: customjava
$ printf 'customjava -version'"\n" | ssh -t localhost
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
zsh: command not found: customjava
```

## Fake A Terminal

If a terminal is required I might switch to `expect`; this creates a
fake terminal that the commands will be run in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

spawn -noecho ssh localhost

# assume a prompt containing at least "% " (ZSH)
expect "% "

# replace ZSH with another shell
send -- "exec bash\n"
# assume a prompt of at least "$ "
expect "$ "
send -- "customjava -version\n"
expect "$ "
set version_info $expect_out(buffer)
send -- "exit\n"

puts "got >>>$version_info<<<"
```

but this has other problems, notably error checking and issues detecting
the shell prompt (which someone might fiddle with, for example, so the
first thing to do might be to set the prompt to some known value for
`expect` to match on). It may also fall apart if someone breaks the
interactive shell configuration in any of innumerable ways. Maybe run
`/bin/sh` and hope that is not `bash`? But then you may need to
configure `sh` for the custom java. This leads to...

### Remove the Configuration from the Shell

Yet another way to solve this would be to write a special command on the
SSH server, probably an exec wrapper, that correctly configures the
environment and then runs the `java` or whatever command. Then you could
run `setup-our-env bash` (an interactive shell for the humans) or
`setup-our-env java -version` (an easy command to run over SSH without
the complication of an interactive shell). An exec wrapper could be as
simple as:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/custom/java/bin:$PATH
exec "$@"
```

In other words, the environment settings for the custom java version
would not be all mixed up with the interactive shell configuration and
thus could be applied to any required command.

Comment: An excellent answer, deserving of a bit more credit than it's gotten after 2k views.